# Histogram is skipping values from my vector

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector:
`x <- c(3570309,583696,102355,10749)`

I am trying to plot x as a histogram.

When I do `hist(x)` my plot comes out weirdly.

[Image of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZxdI.png)

I want the bottom axis to be labelled as 1, 2, 3, 4 and the side axis to start from 0 and increase by 500000 up to 4000000. How can I do this easily?

Comment: What you are describing does not sound like a histogram. Sounds like you just want a bar plot. Try `barplot(x)`

Comment: I need it to be a histogram, this is a homework task so I can't use a bar plot as the questioned specified for us to plot the histogram of x.

Comment: That just doesn't make any sense. I think your teacher might not know what a histogram is. There's a [definition on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). It's for binning values into groups and summarizing their frequency. You don't seem to want to do any binning with your data. You should ask your teacher for help with homework.

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry, I forgot to mention that they are in groups, but we only know that from the question and all we are given is the vector. I am extremely new to R so I'm not sure what to do with it. I wanted the bottom axis to be labelled as 1,2,3 and 4 because those are the groups. 3570309 belongs to 1, 583696 belongs to 2, 102355 belongs to 3, 10749 belongs to 4. The number itself is the frequency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comment, then re-create the original vector using `rep`:

```
x <- c(rep(1, 3570309), rep(2, 583696), rep(3, 102355), rep(4, 10749))
hist(x)
```

Comment: That worked,thanks. Is there any way to change the bottom axis so that it isn't spaced so awkwardly? As in make the width of the columns bigger?

Comment: You have to use the ```hist``` function as part of your homework?  If not, you could create a histogram with barplot as @MrFlick was suggesting: ```barplot(height = c(3570309, 583696, 102355, 10749), names.arg = c(1, 2, 3, 4), main='Histogram')```.  Type ?barplot to see other aesthetic controls.

Comment: I guess I'll just do that since the question only says to "plot the histogram"(?). Thanks!